# Dimension of Query and Key Tensor in MultiHeadAttention

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, transformer-model, attention-model

I am confused about the dimensions that are mentioned for query and key tensors in the documentation of `MultiHeadAttention` Layer in Keras documentation https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/multi_head_attention/

> **query**: Query Tensor of shape (B, T, dim)

> **value**: Value Tensor of shape (B, S, dim).

Here I am presuming that `T` and `S` corresponds to Sequence of words fed in the model which should be same then why they are unequal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is useful when query and key value pair have different input dimension for sequence.

This case can arise in the case of the second `MultiHeadAttention()` attention layer in the `Decoder`. This will be different as the input of `K(key)` and `V(value)` to this layer will come from the `Encoder()` while the `Q(query)` will come from the first `MultiHeadAttention()` layer of `Decoder`.
[image]